# Auto Load JS Notification when browser loads

Tags: jquery

I have downloaded this multiple notification script from [here](https://github.com/mickeyren/jquery-notifications). I want to use this script as an notification for users to notify as they login. But not on click method. How can I change and make a successful one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  i understood your question correctly, i think you want to load/call some function / execute some code as soon as page loads. If yes the please use $(document).ready().
something like this,

```
$(document).ready(/* your code */);
```

PFB link for more details,

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried but no luck, <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready((function(){
$.n('Test test!'});});
</script>

Comment: no need to include it in a function. Please just call try that method like,    $(document).ready($.n('Test test!'));